# JAXB XJC Two declarations cause a collision. Customized binding cannot be honored

Tags: binding, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I would like to generate JAXB classes from this schema file:
http://www.taxonx.org/schema/v1/taxonx1.xsd

I resolved a couple of naming collisions caused by the imported mods-3-1.xsd using customized bindings as follows:

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">

  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-1.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings
        node="//xsd:complexType[@name='relatedItemType']/xsd:attribute[@name='type']">
        <jxb:property name="type2" />
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings
        node="//xsd:attributeGroup[@name='language']/xsd:attribute[@name='lang']">
        <jxb:property name="lang2" />
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings
        node="//xsd:complexType[@name='titleInfoType']/xsd:complexContent/xsd:extension/xsd:attribute[@name='type']">
        <jxb:property name="type3" />
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings
        node="//xsd:complexType[@name='nameType']/xsd:attribute[@name='type']">
        <jxb:property name="type4" />
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings
        node="//xsd:complexType[@name='unstructuredText']/xsd:simpleContent/xsd:extension/xsd:attribute[@name='type']">
        <jxb:property name="type5" />
    </jxb:bindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

When I want to generate classes I still get the following error:

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
line 468 of http://digir.net/schema/conceptual/darwin/manis/1.21/darwin2.xsd

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
line 326 of http://digir.sourceforge.net/schema/protocol/2003/1.0/digir.xsd

Failed to produce code.
```

When I add another customized binding..

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://digir.net/schema/conceptual/darwin/manis/1.21/darwin2.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings
        node="//xsd:element[@name='requiredList' and @substitutionGroup='digir:requiredList']">
        <jxb:property name="requiredList2" />
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I get another error:

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] compiler was unable to honor this property customization. It is attached to a     
wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
line 34 of file:/C:/git/charaparser%20-%20Copy/resources/io/darwinCore/mods-3-1-
bindings.xml

[ERROR] (the above customization is attached to the following location in the schema)
line 468 of http://digir.net/schema/conceptual/darwin/manis/1.21/darwin2.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

A very good answer is here:

[http://blog.lunatech.com/2008/10/17/generating-kml-restful-clients](http://web.archive.org/web/20150510110454/http://blog.lunatech.com/2008/10/17/generating-kml-restful-clients)

In short, use `<jaxb:factoryMethod name="RequiredList2"/>` customization.

Answer (score 0):

We can use as below .I got the same error and resolved by using factoryMethod.

Command : xjc -d src -extension -b demo.xjb demo.xsd

```
 demo.xjb
 ================
 <jxb:bindings 
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
 version="2.1">
 <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="demo.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='itemType']">
            <jxb:factoryMethod  name="Item"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
 </jxb:bindings>
 </jxb:bindings>


demo.xsd
===============
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="2.1">
 <xs:complexType name="itemType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:class name="Item"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:schema>
```