# JAXB binding XBRL element does not work

Tags: eclipse, xpath, binding, jaxb, xbrl

I am trying to generate localised XBRL classes with JAXB in Eclipse, but I have been getting an error:

```
[ERROR] Property "Title" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict. 
line 145 of http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xl-2003-12-31.xsd

[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
line 151 of http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xl-2003-12-31.xsd
```

As the error suggests, an element and an attribute name conflicts. These are lines 145 and 151:

```
<element ref="xl:title" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
<attribute ref="xlink:title" use="optional" />
```

So I'd need to rename either (or both). This is what I've been trying to do - bind the element title to titleElement:

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xl="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/XLink" 
  schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xl-2003-12-31.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings node="//element[@ref='xl:title']">
        <jxb:property ref="xl:titleElement"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

This produces the following error, plus the original "title already defined" errors:

```
[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "//element[@ref='xl:title']" results in empty target node
line 6 of titleElementAttributeFixer.xjb
```

Suggestions to get it working?

EDIT: as helderdarocha suggested, my expression was wrong. I am new to XML and XPath, and it was a bit confusing since the element does not have the "xs:" namespace typed excplicitly. After I fixed that error, I got another one:

```
[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "//xs:element[@ref='xl:title']" results in too many (3) target nodes
```

As all the "ref" attributes need to be updated, I put the tag "multiple='true'" in the binding. Now I am getting the following error, and cannot figure out how to solve it:

```
[ERROR] cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'ref' is not allowed to appear in element 'jxb:property'.
```

Ideas for this? I do want to bind the contents in the attribute 'ref' for the element in question to another name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem after all by applying these SO questions:
[JAXB fails to generate Java classes for XBRL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913445/jaxb-fails-to-generate-java-classes-for-xbrl)
[JAXB XJC Two declarations cause a collision. Customized binding cannot be honored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958364/jaxb-xjc-two-declarations-cause-a-collision-customized-binding-cannot-be-honore?rq=1)

So after I solved the original problem, I had additional problems with objectfactory collisions, which I fixed as well. This is how my working bindings.xjb looks in general:

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
version="2.1">

    <bindings schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xl-2003-12-31.xsd" 
        node="//xsd:schema//xsd:element[@name='title']">
        <property name="xlTitle"/>
    </bindings>

    <bindings schemaLocation="<local_dimension_file_D002>.xsd"
        node="//xsd:schema//xsd:element[@name='AcceleratedDepreciation']"> 
        <factoryMethod name="AcceleratedDepreciationD002"/>
    </bindings>

    ...many more objectfactory collisions solved...
</bindings>
```

I hope this helps other XBRL/XML/JAXB newcomers to get started.

Comment: Do you still have the object factory collisions part? Could you please share? Trying to parse xbrl with xjc

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression is incorrect. Your bindings XML declares an `xs` prefix to qualify all XML Schema elements, but your XPath expression tries to find an `element` element from no-namespace since it's not qualified.

You should use:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@ref='xl:title']">
    <jxb:property ref="xl:titleElement"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: That solved the original problem, however the schema still cannot be parsed as I am facing another problem. Do you have ideas for that one?